# yum install specific version Nothing to do

Tags: rpm, yum

I use a local repository to install new versions of my project.
If I run Yum Install Package, then I am offered to install the latest version available in the repository, but when specifying a specific version I get an error:

```
yum install packagename-1.2.3.45678-0
Loaded plugins: security
Setting up Install Process
extra | 2.9 kB 00:00 ...
extra/primary_db | 8.2 kB 00:00 ...
No package packagename-1.2.3.45678-0 available.
Error: Nothing to do


Contents of the file package.repo
[extra]
name=package-folder
#baseurl=http://xxx.xx.xxx.xx/package-folder
baseurl=file:///var/www/html/package-folder
gpgcheck=0
enabled=1
----------------------
Contents of the file yum.conf

[main]
cachedir=/var/cache/yum/$basearch/$releasever
keepcache=0
debuglevel=2
logfile=/var/log/yum.log
exactarch=1
obsoletes=1
gpgcheck=1
plugins=1
installonly_limit=5
```

However, I found a workaround to use the command "yum downgrade install packagename"
This command allows you to return to the previous version, but also does not work when specifying a specific version. the error is the same as with the command "yum install packagename-version

Q:
How to make it work with any versions of software?
if you more information, I can send all that is required

Comment: also your output does not correspond to the rest of your question. In the output you show you get "No package available"; but the rest of your question is interesting. Please make sure you paste the correct output.

Comment: what error are you getting? perhaps the version does not exist?

Answer (score 0):

I am sadly just as disappointed as you in `yum`. Afaik `yum` does not have a command to *install this version whether it is a downgrade or upgrade*... A workaround that I use:

```
yum downgrade packagename-1.2.3.45678-0 && yum install packagename-1.2.3.45678-0
```

strangely none of these commands fail if nothing is to be installed; so you can just chain them. In this case either of the commands will do the installation; the other will say "Nothing to do".